# mashup for "shopping.com" and amazon APIs?

Tags: php, e-commerce, mashup

I am creating mashup website using amazon and shopping.com APIs. But I am not able to figure out how to get specific product, which is common on both the APIs? and how to display respective price?

How to Get specific product using amazon APIs as well as Shopping APIs?

My thoughts: for Amazon product search: Itemsearch using parameters like keywords and for shopping.com API i am thinking of using search by keyword. But the problem is I want to get specific product which is same as that of on the Amazon. Any suggestions

I am beginner in this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Shopping.com has a API with documentation

http://developer.shopping.com/docs

You will need the Amazon Product Advertising API to get the Amazon search results

https://affiliate-program.amazon.co.uk/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html

Hope this helps